# Mass sql update of one field with several values?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I have an array that looks like:

```
array(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 3
)
```

Currently I am looping over the array and running a single update along the lines of

```
foreach($array as $position => $id){
   //query = update users set order = ($position+1) where id = $id
}
```

obviously not the actual code, but it get's the point across,

If I have 1000 items in my list, that's 1000 queries,

I was wondering if there was a way to do this all in one query?

Comment: What is in your array? Is that `$position` or `$id`?

Comment: I will point out that even with a large loop, if you use an API supporting prepared statements like PDO or MySQLi, you can prepare the query once and execute it 1000 times, which will result in a sizable savings in total execution time since the query isn't being recompiled 1000x.

Comment: start a transaction, and with a loop submit a query each time, push errors to another array to see what failed.

Comment: At the most, we can reduce the `foreach` loop. But how do you suppose you can achieve the same in one single `update` query ? and i agree with Micheal's comment above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the MySQL case statement. I'm not sure whether it would be much faster or not, but here's how it might work:

```
$query = 'UPDATE users SET order = CASE id ';
foreach($array as $position => $id) {
    $query .= 'WHEN '.$id.' THEN "'.($position+1).'" ';
}
$query .= 'ELSE order ENDCASE'; // leave order the same if the id doesn't match the array
// run $query...
```

[MySQL CASE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html)

Comment: this is a very nice way, i'll remeber it too

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible.
You can use your loop to build the query string to fit this [example](http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-and-a-single-sql-query/)

Then executing your query ;)

Comment: @Windwaker. Try to summarize answers here in SO in case the link goes bad someday. Also have you verified that the example you link to works in MySQL?

Comment: I remember I used a similar query to do a mass update. So i did not check it again, right.
Ok , I'm new in answering here, I'll put the code the next time :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `id` is a primary or unique key, you can do this:

```
$tmp = Array();
foreach($array as $position=>$id) {
    $tmp[] = "(".$id.",".($position+1).")";
}
$query = "INSERT INTO users (id,order) VALUES ".implode(",",$tmp)
    ." ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE order=VALUES(order)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the "in" operator -
update users set order = ($position+1) where id in

Comment: This will set every row to have the same `order` value!